# How to decode javascript unicode string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf, ucs2

I found that it is a character of `TWO HEARTS` [here](http://www.charbase.com/1f495-unicode-two-hearts). I tried to decode it:

```
a = '\ud83d\udc95'
a.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```

How to get the right symbol?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error message?

Comment: Your link shows `u'\U0001f495'` as the Python escape; instead, here you use the Java/JavaScript escape. Why?

Comment: This is my received data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**json**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to help you solve different `Unicode`.

```
import json

a = '\ud83d\udc95'
m = json.dumps({"k": a})
print(json.loads(m)["k"])  #
```

Answer (score 2):

The page you link to tells you the

> Python Escape u'\U0001f495'

Use it:

```
>>> u'\U0001f495'
''
```

Comment: Thank you Lutz. However, how to transform from `\ud83d\udc95` to `\U0001f495`? How to do the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I cant make a comment, so here is the answer for how to transform`"\uD83D\uDC95".encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16').encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')`