# How to decode javascript-unicode string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf, ucs2

I have this string:

```
{\u0022allow_group_shows\u0022: true, \u0022needs_supporter_to_pm\u0022: true, \u0022ads_zone_ids\u0022: {\u0022300x250,centre\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022300x250,right\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022300x250,left\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022468x60\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022160x600,top\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022160x600,bottom\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022160x600,middle\u0022: \u0022\u0022}, \u0022chat_settings\u0022: {\u0022sort_users_key\u0022: \u0022a\u0022, \u0022silence_broadcasters\u0022: \u0022false\u0022, \u0022highest_token_color\u0022: \u0022darkpurple\u0022, \u0022emoticon_autocomplete_delay\u0022: \u00220\u0022, \u0022ignored_users\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022show_emoticons\u0022: true, \u0022font_size\u0022: \u00229pt\u0022, \u0022b_tip_vol\u0022: \u002210\u0022, \u0022allowed_chat\u0022: \u0022all\u0022, \u0022room_leave_for\u0022: \u0022org\u0022, \u0022font_color\u0022: \u0022#494949\u0022, \u0022font_family\u0022: \u0022default\u0022, \u0022room_entry_for\u0022: \u0022org\u0022, \u0022v_tip_vol\u0022: \u002280\u0022}, \u0022is_age_verified\u0022: true, \u0022flash_host\u0022: \u0022edge143.stream.highwebmedia.com\u0022, \u0022tips_in_past_24_hours\u0022: 0, \u0022dismissible_messages\u0022: [], \u0022show_mobile_site_banner_link\u0022: false, \u0022last_vote_in_past_90_days_down\u0022: false, \u0022server_name\u0022: \u0022113\u0022, \u0022num_users_required_for_group\u0022: 2, \u0022group_show_price\u0022: 18, \u0022is_mobile\u0022: false, \u0022chat_username\u0022: \u0022__anonymous__eiwBXR\u0022, \u0022recommender_hmac\u0022: \u0022dae28e4e9afa15da7c6227af2e8fb8abd85a3714aca8f86f01a53a6dd1377115\u0022, \u0022broadcaster_gender\u0022: \u0022couple\u0022, \u0022hls_source\u0022: \u0022https://localhost/live\u002Dhls/amlst:jimmy_and_amy\u002Dsd\u002De73f4b67186a2ec4c13137607d02470ac61f32b60ac15e691bf33493423ef477_trns_h264/playlist.m3u8\u0022, \u0022allow_show_recordings\u0022: true, \u0022is_moderator\u0022: false, \u0022room_status\u0022: \u0022public\u0022, \u0022edge_auth\u0022: \u0022{\u005C\u0022username\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022__anonymous__eiwBXR\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022org\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022A\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022expire\u005C\u0022:1590669977,\u005C\u0022sig\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022454d96141c66fb42f74e9620b9d79e937de3a774a5687021f8650cc4f563d371\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022room\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022jimmy_and_amy\u005C\u0022}\u0022, \u0022is_supporter\u0022: false, \u0022chat_password\u0022: \u0022{\u005C\u0022username\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022__anonymous__eiwBXR\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022org\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022A\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022expire\u005C\u0022:1590669977,\u005C\u0022sig\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022454d96141c66fb42f74e9620b9d79e937de3a774a5687021f8650cc4f563d371\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022room\u005C\u0022:\u005C\u0022jimmy_and_amy\u005C\u0022}\u0022, \u0022room_pass\u0022: \u0022b5b2408cd91e6c595a3f732a5b7b1567b566bcc92f384ce5e6a00a26a24fb5c7\u0022, \u0022low_satisfaction_score\u0022: false, \u0022tfa_enabled\u0022: false, \u0022room_title\u0022: \u0022(STEP SIS CUM FACE) shh... Luna is here and dont know what we are doing #hairy #creampie #stockings #new #lush [3536 tokens remaining]\u0022, \u0022satisfaction_score\u0022: {\u0022down_votes\u0022: 15, \u0022up_votes\u0022: 67, \u0022percent\u0022: 82, \u0022max\u0022: 31222657}, \u0022viewer_username\u0022: \u0022AnonymousUser\u0022, \u0022hidden_message\u0022: \u0022\u0022, \u0022following\u0022: false, \u0022wschat_host\u0022: \u0022https://chatws\u002D45.stream.highwebmedia.com/ws\u0022, \u0022has_studio\u0022: false, \u0022num_followed\u0022: 0, \u0022spy_private_show_price\u0022: 30, \u0022hide_satisfaction_score\u0022: false, \u0022broadcaster_username\u0022: \u0022jimmy_and_amy\u0022, \u0022ignored_emoticons\u0022: [], \u0022apps_running\u0022: \u0022[[\u005C\u0022Tip Goal\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022\u005C\u005C/apps\u005C\u005C/app_details\u005C\u005C/tip\u002Dgoal\u005C\u005C/?slot\u003D0\u005C\u0022],[\u005C\u0022Ultra Bot \u002D 4Sci\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022\u005C\u005C/apps\u005C\u005C/app_details\u005C\u005C/ultra\u002Dbot\u002D4sci\u005C\u005C/?slot\u003D2\u005C\u0022],[\u005C\u0022Roll The Dice\u005C\u0022,\u005C\u0022\u005C\u005C/apps\u005C\u005C/app_details\u005C\u005C/roll\u002Dthe\u002Ddice\u002D5\u005C\u005C/?slot\u003D3\u005C\u0022]]\u0022, \u0022token_balance\u0022: 0, \u0022private_min_minutes\u0022: 10, \u0022viewer_gender\u0022: \u0022m\u0022, \u0022allow_anonymous_tipping\u0022: false, \u0022num_users_waiting_for_group\u0022: 0, \u0022last_vote_in_past_24_hours\u0022: null, \u0022is_widescreen\u0022: true, \u0022num_viewers\u0022: 1672, \u0022broadcaster_on_new_chat\u0022: false, \u0022private_show_price\u0022: 30, \u0022num_followed_online\u0022: 0, \u0022allow_private_shows\u0022: true}
```

and I want to decode it in python to view to make it easier for me to send it over the internet into our android app... anyways that why I am here it should look like

```
"{"allow_group_shows": true, "needs_supporter_to_pm": true, "ads_zone_ids": {"300x250,centre": "", "300x250,right": "", "300x250,left": "", "468x60": "", "160x600,top": "", "160x600,bottom": "", "160x600,middle": ""}, "chat_settings": {"sort_users_key": "a", "silence_broadcasters": "false", "highest_token_color": "darkpurple", "emoticon_autocomplete_delay": "0", "ignored_users": "", "show_emoticons": true, "font_size": "9pt", "b_tip_vol": "10", "allowed_chat": "all", "room_leave_for": "org", "font_color": "#494949", "font_family": "default", "room_entry_for": "org", "v_tip_vol": "80"}, "is_age_verified": true, "flash_host": "edge306.stream.highwebmedia.com", "tips_in_past_24_hours": 0, "dismissible_messages": [], "show_mobile_site_banner_link": false, "last_vote_in_past_90_days_down": false, "server_name": "115", "num_users_required_for_group": 2, "group_show_price": 18, "is_mobile": false, "chat_username": "bom4b5", "recommender_hmac": "ed05e292bb82262255a96944d81bb04dc2d248ca69fff35cf5d7015889c005b1", "broadcaster_gender": "couple", "hls_source": "https://***/live-edge/****-sd-e73f4b67186a2ec4c13137607d02470ac61f32b60***%22%7D", "allow_show_recordings": true, "is_moderator": false, "room_status": "public", "edge_auth": "{\"username\":\"bom4b5\",\"org\":\"A\",\"expire\":1590666696,\"sig\":\"49b6844fde2c47c2430bd05946b6cfbc9c7864788b9236d7f5af5ff88efd3f95\",\"room\":\"jimmy_and_amy\"}", "is_supporter": false, "chat_password": "****", "room_pass": "b5b2408cd91e6c595a3f732a5b7b1567b566bcc92f384ce5e6a00a26a24fb5c7", "low_satisfaction_score": false, "tfa_enabled": false, "room_title": "(STEP SIS CUM FACE) shh... Luna is here and dont know what we are doing #hairy #creampie #stockings #new #lush [4310 tokens remaining]", "satisfaction_score": {"down_votes": 15, "up_votes": 67, "percent": 82, "max": 31222657}, "viewer_username": "bom4b5", "hidden_message": "", "following": false, "wschat_host": "https://chatws-45.stream.highwebmedia.com/ws", "has_studio": false, "num_followed": 0, "spy_private_show_price": 30, "hide_satisfaction_score": false, "broadcaster_username": "jimmy_and_amy", "ignored_emoticons": [], "apps_running": "[[\"Tip Goal\",\"\\/apps\\/app_details\\/tip-goal\\/?slot=0\"],[\"Ultra Bot - 4Sci\",\"\\/apps\\/app_details\\/ultra-bot-4sci\\/?slot=2\"],[\"Roll The Dice\",\"\\/apps\\/app_details\\/roll-the-dice-5\\/?slot=3\"]]", "token_balance": 0, "private_min_minutes": 10, "viewer_gender": "f", "allow_anonymous_tipping": false, "num_users_waiting_for_group": 0, "last_vote_in_past_24_hours": null, "is_widescreen": true, "num_viewers": 331, "broadcaster_on_new_chat": false, "private_show_price": 30, "num_followed_online": 0, "allow_private_shows": true}"
```

I tried [How to decode javascript unicode string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769903/how-to-decode-javascript-unicode-string-in-python)
it worked but the only one issue is that I cant decode it after I split

```
gett = s.get("https://localhost.com/34534535/")
# print(gett.text + "\n\n\n\n")

m = json.dumps({"k": gett.text})  # decodes it

# split
testt = (json.loads(m)["k"]).split('window.initialRoomDossier = "')
testt = testt[1].split('";')

final = testt[0]  # show the same
```

the thing is that if I load it from a string like

```
a = "{\u0022allow_group_shows\u0022: true, \u0022nee..."
```

it does work but not after I split

Comment: "`json.dumps({"k": gett.text})#Decodes it`" — Nope, `json.dumps` ***encodes*** a Python object *to* JSON… That step seems extremely superfluous!?

Comment: `{\u0022allow_group_shows\u0022: true ...` looks like the JSON serialisation is messed up, you should fix that instead trying to parse the string in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it

```
import js2py


#split
splitt = (json.loads(m)["k"]).split('window.initialRoomDossier = "')
splitt = splitt[1].split('";')

final = str(splitt[0])
final = 'var kek = "'+final+'";'#Turning it into javascript code (Later we will run it)


#Javascript Virtual Machine
context = js2py.EvalJs({'python_sum': sum})  

#Slides the sexy code
context.execute(final)#Running the javascript code
#print (context.kek)#

m3u8_url = json.loads(context.kek)["hls_source"]
```